# Setting up an API/website in a firebase project

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-hosting

I am working on a little website on Firebase, which is meant to be used as an API for customer sites.
Since this is the first time I build something like this I have many questions on the way.
This site is the second site on the Firebase project. The first site (a more standard website) already works as intended.

Here is the *index.js* file:

```
import {initializeApp} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js'
import {getAnalytics} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js'
import {getDatabase,ref,onValue} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ".....",
    authDomain: ".....",
    databaseURL: ".....",
    projectId: ".....",
    storageBucket: ".....",
    messagingSenderId: ".....",
    appId: ".....",
    measurementId: "....."
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getDatabase();
.... // No code for now.
```

In case this may be useful here is the *index.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <title>API</title>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>API-PAGE</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally this is the problem I am now facing, for which I need some help:

I see this error in the Web Developer Tools Console of my browser, when I load the site:

```
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 4
Cookie “_ga_86RGDHBP0R” has been rejected for invalid domain. js:147:994
Cookie “_ga” has been rejected for invalid domain. js:147:994
```

What is wrong? What did I forget to do?